# highcharts is adding an extra day after DST ends when useUtc option is false

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is this a highcharts bug, or am I doing something really dumb? (hover over Nov 6 and compare the xaxis and the tooltip dates)

https://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/8232/

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false,
    },
});  // look at the fiddle to see the error going on
```

[image]

Comment: Everything works fine on my PC (my timezone is UTC+01:00). Please provide the image of your output and what is wrong with it.

Comment: @KamilKulig - updated with a screenshot... DST ended Nov 5 and that's where the weirdness ensues.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this issue. Have you tried using `useUTC: true` along with `timezoneOffset`? **Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/wkrfreq5/

Answer (score 0):

Nov 5th was daylight savings.  So, it appears some silliness is happening with the date/time and that hour.

I always use UTC with highCharts, so I haven't run into this.  But, it does feel like a bug.

The following with dates in UTC solves the problem.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: true,
    },
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        showLastLabel: true,
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: '%b %e',
        },
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2017,10,1, 0), 0],
            [Date.UTC(2017,10,2, 0), 0],
            [Date.UTC(2017,10,3, 0), 0],
            [Date.UTC(2017,10,4, 0), 0],
            [Date.UTC(2017,10,5, 0), 4],
            [Date.UTC(2017,10,6, 0), 0],
            [Date.UTC(2017,10,7, 0), 0],
            [Date.UTC(2017,10,8, 0), 0],
            [Date.UTC(2017,10,9, 0), 0],
            [Date.UTC(2017,10,10, 0), 0],
        ],
        type: 'line'
    }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/8235/